# How to set a remote connection to a Vagrant container using "Visual Studio Code Remote - SSH"?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vagrant, vagrant-windows, vscode-remote

I'm exploring the new set extensions called VSCode Remote Pack and I want to connect to a Vagrant container using the Remote Container extension. Using a Windows 10 OS, how could I do that?

I tried the extension but it requests me to have Docker installed, what I suppose from that is that it only works for Docker containers. But I wonder if somebody have already managed to connect to a Vagrant box.

This are the docs from the extension: `https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry for updating this so late.

The solution was pretty simple, as @MnZrk commented, what it needs to be done for setting up the connection is the following:

- Run `vagrant ssh-config > some-file.txt`. This will generate a file with the configuration to run using SSH. Here an example of that file:

```
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile C:/Users/User/project/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
  ForwardAgent yes
  ForwardX11 yes
```

Notice that the host name is `default`, you could rename it to whatever you want so  you could identify it more easily.

- Copy the content of `some-file.txt` inside your SSH configuration file. This file could be edit directly from vscode by pressing `F1` and writing `Remote-SSH: Open Configuration File...`, then you select the file you use for ssh configuration. After that file opens, just copy the content of `some-file.txt` there.
- Finally, just press again `F1` and type `Remote-SSH: Connect to Host...`, choose the connection with the host name `default` or the want you wrote in the first step, and that's all.

Answer (score 11):

VS Code Remote containers currently only support Docker (its implementation executes `docker` commands). Please [open a feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/new/choose) if you would like to see other tools supported.

As an alternative, you could try using [Remote SSH](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) to connect to vagrant containers. That should work but will require some extra container setup

Comment: You're right! Actually, it was pretty easy to connect using `Remote SSH` :D

Comment: @CarlosCórdovaS. Can you explain how you did this? I'm having trouble with the user@hostname step. Not sure where I get these values from.

Comment: Dito as above. I can SSH into the server, but not sure how to connect to a remote container.

Comment: @davidatthepark You get a ssh config from `vagrant ssh-config` and put it to the config file VSCode uses by `F1 -> Remote-SSH: Open configuration File...` The vagrant container should appear in the `F1 -> Remote-SSH: Connect to Host...` list.

Comment: So once you have connected to a vagrant VM, how do you attach a debugger to a Docker container inside said VM?